# How to find the eigenvalues of a block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I have a block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A & Z & O\\
Y & A & Z\\
O & Y & A\end{bmatrix}$$

where

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
Y=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
Z=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

I need to find its eigenvalues with out any scientific instruments. I know that the $k$-th eigenvalues of a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix is

$$\lambda_k = A-2\sqrt{YZ} \cos⁡\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right).$$

However, here, the elements in the matrix $M$ are blocks. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.